# Trouble understanding these regular expressions

Tags: regex

I have having trouble understanding what exactly these regular expressions below mean. Could someone provide an example?

```
^cat$ 
^$ 
^
```

Answer (score 2):

`^` matches the start of a line.
`$` matches the end of a line.

`^cat$` matches all lines whose contents are exactly `cat`.
 `^$` matches all empty lines.
`^` matches the start of all lines.